# Package tcsh shell inside a windows application

Tags: linux, windows, shell, csh, tcsh

I have a customer script in csh, which I need to include in an add-on package for multiple platforms.
It internally sets environment variable values as platform specific e.g.

```
!/bin/csh -f
setenv USERPLATFORM [win32|lnx86|sun5]
set defaultlibpath=$LIBPATH/lib.$USERPLATFORM
```

UNIX/LINUX systems have no problem running this script. But I need this script to run in Windows, on systems WITHOUT cygwin installed. Is there any tcsh shell executable for windows that I can add to my package and call it from my own platform independent proprietary extension language with appropriate arguments (there is a system command in my extension language which can call any system executable).
An alternative could be to write an equivalent bat file, but it may again need change when the customer brings change in the parent csh script.

The commands in use inside the script file are basename, setenv, eval.

Comment: Google for ["C-shell considered harmful"](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html) and convert your script to Posix shell

Comment: 1. Will making it POSIX compliant make it work right-out in Windows?
2. It is a customer-provided script and I can't change it myself.